# Abstract class implements interface, can implementation of interface method determine subclass extending abstract super class?

Tags: java, interface

Given an interface:

```
public interface GoAlgorithm
{
  public void go();
}
```

A class which implements the interface:

```
public class GoByFlyingFast implements GoAlgorithm
{
  public void go()
  {
    System.out.println("Now I'm flying FAAAAST. Woo-hoo!");
  }
}
```

An abstract class

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
  private GoAlgorithm goAlgorithm;

  public Vehicle()
  {
    System.out.printf("A new vehicle has entered the race! \n");
  }

  public void setGoAlgorithm(GoAlgorithm algorithm)
  {
    this.goAlgorithm = algorithm;
  }

  public void go()
  {
    this.goAlgorithm.go();
  }
}
```

A class extending the abstract class:

```
public class Tomcat extends Vehicle
{
  public Tomcat()
  {
    setGoAlgorithm(new GoByFlyingFast());
  }
}
```

(Code examples from Design Patterns for Dummies)

Is there a way, within the abstract class's implementation of the interface's method, to determine the subclass of the object invoking the method of the interface?

Can go() determine if a Tomcat object is invoking the go() method as defined by the Vehicle class?

Apologies if this question has already been posed. As evidenced by this question's title, I'm struggling to word my question concisely.

Thank you!

EDIT: Pure curiosity question

Comment: *Can go() determine if a Tomcat object is invoking the go() method as defined by the Vehicle class?* With this design, no, it is not possible.

Comment: "Can go() determine if a Tomcat object is invoking the go() method as defined by the Vehicle class?" First things first, why do you want to know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically yes. You can get the current stack trace with `Thread.getStackTrace()`, analyze it and look at the dynamic class of your caller. However, this would be VERY bad design.

Alternatively you can have your subclasses implement a `getName()` function, which returns their classname, so you could access that in your superclass.

In any case, it is good design if your (abstract) classes do not change their behavior based on which class is subclassing them. So there should not be a need for obtaining such information.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I agree there is no need but I am incurably curious; more interested in the "is it possible", however ugly or useless. I'll take a look at Thread.

Comment: @IdusOrtus it would be better if you add a setter method in your interface to specify the client of this interface, so you can set the current instance of the class that uses the interface , like `Tomcat` in its constructor. But note that this is an ugly design (not as bad as `Thread#getStackTrace` usage) and should be avoided due to generating class coupling.

Comment: This is equivalent to the getter method I suggested. You would just not use the getter method but a field, same principle.

Comment: Thanks again for the input! I see that your suggestions would provide what I'm asking for, and agree re: poor design, increases coupling, and any solution will likely be ugly. So there's no way to do this generically or dynamically? Something akin to dynamic lookup?

Comment: @IdusOrtus no, there isn't. And there should not be a way. Why do you want to know which client uses an exact implementation of your interface to begin with?

Comment: Luiggi is right. And again dynamic lookup would just be some kind of syntactic sugar to the `getName()` variant.

Comment: Ya, I know, this is a useless question with no real practical application to proper code :) Honestly, why would this exact functionality be provided in the language at all, etc. It does help my understanding of the api, and I appreciate your time spent assisting me.

Comment: Upvoting is always appreciated ;)